# Getting Format Exception while parsing token with '|' in jsonDecode()

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dio

Getting the format exception while passing the token with '|' inside jsonDecode().
[image]

```
final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    value = pref.get("token") as String;
    if (value?.isEmpty ?? true) {
      return null;
    } else {
      final Map<String, dynamic> map = await _parseJson(value);
      return OldToken.fromJson(map);
    }

static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _parseJson(String text) {
    return compute(_parseAndDecode, text);
  }

static Map<String, dynamic> _parseAndDecode(String response) {
    return jsonDecode(response) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  }
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20should%20only%20be%20used,)%20or%20press%20Ctrl%20%2B%20K%20.

Comment: Cant see your issue due to images blocked here. Better provide in text form.

Comment: I think it would help others understand better if you could post the fragment of JSON input on which it's failing.

Comment: which line is getting error??

Comment: I am getting format exception inside jsonDecode() method @JanviPatel

Comment: @gowthamanC what is in response try to print it

Comment: post your json that you want to parse

Comment: I think the problem may be that this is just a string and not a json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use SharedPreferences you retrieve directly a String, so you don't need to decode a json value.